# Pointwise convergence implies mean square convergence on a finite length space.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I am trying to prove that pointwise convergence implies mean square convergence on $[-\pi,\pi]$. I ma not even sure this is true but (my measure theory classes) have shown me that it is. However I am trying to produce a proof that does not end on 'and since the space is finite then...'. Is there a way to produce a simple, nice proof of this fact without having to explictily mention the finiteness of the space or the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this is true. Take 
$$
f_{n}:=n\cdot\chi_{(0,1/n]}
$$

then $f_n$ converges pointwise to $0$, but:
$$
||f_n-0||_{L^2}=||f_n||_{L^2}=\sqrt{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f_n^2(t)dt}=\sqrt{\int_0^{\frac{1}{n}} n^2dt}=\sqrt{n}\rightarrow \infty 
$$

This will not work even if you assume that the functions are continuous (build "triangles" over $[0,1/n]$ with height $n$).